# DIV display block state after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cookie

I am trying to save the state with a cookie using jquery but no luck. Can someone check what is wrong with my code?

```
$('.slide1').click(function() {
    $('.target1').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('.target1');
    });
    $.cookie('form_visible', $('.target1').css('display','block').toString());
    return false;
});         
$(function() {
    if($.cookie('form_visible') == 'true') {
        $('.target1').css('display','block');
    } else {
        $('.target1').css('display','none');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J9zQm/

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work, because you didn't include jQuery nor the cookie plugin. Please don't link a live demo if it isn't a live demo.

Comment: i thought jsfiddle has the libraries and i am not sure what cookie plugin you are talking about, i found this code on another post and it worked but after i made some changes to make it work with my website it stopped working

Comment: you need a plugin in order to use `$.cookie`

Comment: is this good? <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: This is the jQuery library, you need the [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) for jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems:

1. You need a plugin

   In order to use `$.cookie`, you need a [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/). You don't seem to know that.
2. You are trying to store `"[object Object]"`

   ```
   $('.target1').css('display','block')
   ```

   returns an object (i.e. `$('.target1')`)

   Then,

   ```
   $('.target1').css('display','block').toString()
   ```

   returns

   ```
   "[object Object]"
   ```
3. `$('.target1')` is empty

   You use

   ```
   $('.target1').slideToggle('slow', function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('.target1');
   });
   ```

   That is:

   - If `$('.target1')` is empty, you do nothing
   - If `$('.target1')` is not empty, you remove its class `'.target1'`, so that following `$('.target1')` will be empty.

---

Here you have a working example of what you want, but using `sessionStorage` instead of `$.cookie` since I don't know how it works.

JS:

```
var $target1 = $('.target1');
$target1.toggleClass('hidden', sessionStorage.getItem('form_visible') != 'true');
$('.slide1').click(function() {
    $target1.slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
    });
    sessionStorage.setItem('form_visible', $target1.hasClass('hidden'));
});
```

CSS:

```
.target1.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J9zQm/1/)

Comment: it seem to work but it breaks out of the div i think when i try to move the content under .target1 to the middle it shoots to the left after it opens up

Comment: @Bamba I don't understand. Are you talking about my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J9zQm/1/)?

Comment: yeah if you add  width:60%; and margin:0 auto; to both .slide1 and .target1, you will see what i mean, it doesn't stay in the middle like supposed to

Comment: @Bamba Try `text-align: center` if you want to center the text. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J9zQm/2/)

Comment: it worked! i guess it's a matter of where you place that and .target1.hidden was making it weird. Thanks for all your help, much appreciated!

Comment: there is a little problem when refreshing, the div opens and closes (or will go to the same state as it was before the refresh)

Comment: any idea why it does that? it opens and closes everything in a split second when the page loads

Comment: @Bamba I can't reproduce this problem in the jsfiddle. If you are talking about your site, check if `.target1.hidden{display:none;}` is in a stylesheet in the head.

Comment: yeah i have it set to display:none; jsfiddle doesn't do that for some reason.. could it be something to do with server connection? im using a free hosting account so maybe that's the issue

Comment: @Bamba If it's in the head, the browser should download the stylesheet before starting loading the body. Check the Network tab in your browser's developer tools to see if the stylesheet is downloaded at the beginning.

Comment: it was called after all the meta tags but even moving it to the very top did change anything, and i am using localhost too and it does the same. When you open the page where the sliders are on, you clearly see all of them open then close and only the one that was opened before reopens to that state again. could i be missing a jquery plugin?

Comment: @Bamba No, I don't think that's related to jQuery. But don't know the answer, better ask another question asking why your stylesheet is loaded too late.

Comment: figured out the problem. i had godday's site seal of my domain and when i removed it the problem was gone. something to do with their retarded script i guess